# Iterating through a pointer to a vector of pointers

Tags: iphone, c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am trying to write an iPhone game using cocos2d and Box2D, which means I have to mix between Objective-C and C++. I have a question regarding using pointers to objects of gameLevels and levelObjects that I have created.

I have a class called GameLevel which contains a vector of levelObjects. I thought that using pointers was the way to do it, to make sure I use as little memory as possible. That means that my vector is

```
std::vector<LevelObject*>* levelObjects;
```

The LevelObject class contains the sprite, b2bodyDef and so on, all pointers as well.

The problems started when I wanted to iterate through this vector when I wanted to draw a level. The code I wrote was this:

```
-(void)startLevel:(b2World*) world withLevel:(GameLevel*) level{
std::vector<LevelObject*>::iterator it;
for (it = level->getLevelObjects()->begin() ; it != level->getLevelObjects()->end(); ++it) {
    CCSprite* sprite = it->sprite; //Here XCode complaints about "Member reference base type 'LevelObject *' is not a structure or union" and "Use of undeclared identifier 'sprite'". I cannot seem to access any of the objects variables/methods from it->
```

So the question I ask is: Is this a good way to to this, with a pointer to vector of pointers? And why doesn't the iteration work?

Thanks :)

EDIT: getLevelObjects() are:

```
std::vector<LevelObject*>* getLevelObjects(){return levelObjects;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your iterators point to pointers, so you need two dereferences:

```
(*it)->sprite
```

the dereference of the iterator,

```
*it
```

gives you a `LevelObject*`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two levels of indirection, the iterator and the pointer inside the vector.

You need `(*it)` to get to the pointer, and then use `->` to dereference that:

```
CCSprite* sprite = (*it)->sprite;
```